# Complex query to display sub categories when main category is selected

Tags: mysql

I'm new to programming and I'm currently trying to display Main categories + sub categories as a tree.

Menu with categories is already created. Now I want when I click on Main category name to load all products in all sub-categories assigned to this main category. The problem is I don't understand how to construct my query.

In my table categories I store both main cats and sub-cats. When I add sub-category to some main category I store main category ID under parentID column.

Example

```
ID       Name       parentID
426       Main Cat       0
427       sub-cat        426
428       sub-cat 2      426
429       Main cat 2     0
```

products table has `categoryID` column

```
productID    categoryID
   1            427
   2            428
   3            429
```

So when I lick on maincatID=1 it should show me products with id 1 and 2 because they are assigned to `sub-cat` which is assigned to main cat 1

This query I've tried

```
$masterCategory = '426';
$query="SELECT * from products  
LEFT JOIN categories on categories.categoryID = products.categoryID 
WHERE products.categoryID in (" . $masterCategory ."0)";
```

I should get 2 products when I click on `catid=426` because I have two products added to subs which are assigned to `catid=426` ... products 1 and 2.

The problem is that I've got 4-5 empty products with `NULL` everything.. which isn't correct.

`Var_dump($query);` return

```
SELECT * from products  
LEFT JOIN categories on categories.categoryID = products.categoryID 
WHERE products.categoryID in (427,428,426,0)
```

`var_dump($masterCategory);` return

```
string(12) "427,428,426,"
```

Note: I've read it about parameterized queries. I've adding parameter in sql just for a testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the below query:

```
SELECT a.ID,c.productID,b.Name,b.parentID
FROM categories a JOIN categories b 
ON(a.ID=b.parentID)
JOIN products c
ON(b.ID=c.categoryID)
WHERE a.ID=<catid>;
```

where catid is the main ID you have to pass.
I have simulated this with the data given above, and I am getting the results as I expected.

```
 ID   productID  Name       parentID  
 426  2          sub-cat 2  426       
 426  1          sub-cat    426
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it returns empty rows `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0043 seconds.)`

Comment: Updated the answer, please see

Comment: This should work, but only if you have one level of sub-categories. If you have more levels, myslq alone would not be a good solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works for now. @Seb currently is one level sub-categories and I don't plan to go deeper :)

Comment: Hit the up-tick if answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT * from products  
    LEFT JOIN categories on categories.categoryID = products.categoryID 
    WHERE categories.categoryID = 426 OR categories.parendID=426;
```